# Self extracting archive/ Installer with environment variable

Tags: windows-installer, installation, archive, advanced-installer, self-extracting

I have a website where people can upload their files for other to download. But I want the person who upload the files first create a installer package, and the path will contain some pre-defined environment variable. Are there any programs that will be suitable for this situation? I prefer a program that is easy to use for users to upload their files into a installer package and free if possible.

I tried using Advanced Installer but couldn't get the Path to include environment variable.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This doesn't look like a good idea from a security point of view. Letting people upload executables (such as a self-extracting archive) for other people to download cries for abuse. How do you know that these executables can be trusted and are not full of viruses or other malware?

Comment: @zett42 Thanks for replying, you brought up a good point, but this website is for internal use at my company, so that's not something I am too concern for now :)

Comment: OK, you may use [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) command-line version to generate self-extracting archives. You may build something around that to make it easy to use for your use case. In simplest case just a batch file which can use the environment variable, if this is still too hard for your users you may create a simple GUI with [AutoIt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt) for instance.

Comment: To get environment variable with AutoIt: [Function EnvGet](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/EnvGet.htm). Here is an [example for HTTP request using AutoIt](https://beamtic.com/http-requests-autoit) (under "POST request"). You would propably want to replace `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by `application/octet-stream` because you are uploading binary file.

Comment: I'm trying to understand.  Are you trying to automate creating installers for standardized addins or something?

Comment: @zett42 I found another solution using makesfx, thank you for the help!

Comment: I also got a similar need so I wrote a simple program to do the job. [Here is the source code && binary](https://github.com/BLumia/pineapple-package-manager) and feel free to do necessary modify and re-use the code if you also got a similar need.